# Yii saving object data after find

Tags: php, yii

For Yii framework, can we set attribute for save function using object results from find function like below?

```
$proposal = new Proposals;
$proposal_temp = Proposals_temp::model()->find('eid=?', array($users->eid));
$proposal->Attributes = $proposal_temp;
```

Would this actually save the Proposal_temp row into Proposals table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to use the `save()` method. `Attributes` is just an array of columns in the table. You'll have to loop through the results of `$proposal_temp` and save each row. See [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord)